# Синергический или синергетический?

Tags: выбор-слов, прилагательные, неологизмы

В слове `синергия` ударение ставится на предпоследний слог, поэтому мне (интуитивно) кажется некорректно звучащим слово `синергетический`, в отличие от `синергический`.

Который из вариантов верный?

Comment: В словарях есть и то и другое

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эти прилагательные относятся **к разным терминам**: синергия – синерги/ческ/ий, синергетика – синергетич/еск/ий.

**СИНЕРГЕТИКА** [нэ], -и; ж. [от греч. synergētikós - совместный, согласованно действующий] Научно-философский принцип, рассматривающий природу, мир как самоорганизующуюся комплексную систему. <**Синергетический**,  С. подход.

**СИНЕРГИЯ** [нэ], ж. [греч. synergeía - сотрудничество, содружество] 1. Мед. Вариант реакции организма на одновременный приём нескольких лекарств, оказывающих на него комбинированное воздействие. 2. Физиол. Совместное действие каких-л. органов, физиологических систем.

Answer (score 1):

[синерги́я](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/seksolog/199) (др.-греч. *συνεργία* — соучастие, содействие) — совместное действие; *прилаг*. **синергический.**

Синергия в экономике, [синергический эффект](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/econ_dict/19607) — увеличение эффективности деятельности в результате сочетания, соединения, интеграции, слияния отдельных частей в единую систему, благодаря эмерджентности (возникновение новых качеств) полученной системы.

Мне кажется, что можно найти аналогии: хирургия — хирургический, аллергия — аллергический, металлургия — металлургический, асинерги́я — [асинергический](http://www.%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).